# asp.net difference between accessing as local machine or remote client

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

We developp an web application in asp.net Framework 4.7, and we have a difference between accessing the application from the local computer (localhost, or direct name make no difference) and from a remote computer.

The form action is not show with the same information. From the local machine, i get this :

```
<form name="aspnetForm" id="aspnetForm" action="/MediOnlineNet/(S(id55ddmoixefhknices1zwj0))/DefaultPopup2011.aspx?ppname=_MOPPAG_undefined&amp;Mod=1&amp;0&amp;_MOPPAG_undefined&amp;PPID=254&amp;caller=6&amp;agndPatientId=0&amp;agndContactInformationId=0&amp;numAgenda=5081&amp;numResponsable=10746&amp;typeContact=0&amp;canSeePrive=1&amp;ctrlID=ctl00_CPH_ctl00_Uc_agnd_ctactAff_011&amp;contactName=&amp;contactVorName=&amp;contactDate=&amp;contactNoPatient=" method="post">
```

and from an remote computer, I get this :

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post"
action="/MediOnlineNet/(S(yevu1jhfwkrqc3wsx4ag3cot))/DefaultPopup2011.aspx?PPID=258&amp;ppname=_MOPPAG_undefined&amp;Mod=1&amp;isModal=0" id="aspnetForm">
```

And I don't understand why I don't get the same information in each execution.

Any help on this problem ?

Thank you and regards
Philippe RITTER

Comment: Can you  post source code?

Comment: We have found the main problem. It is related to the function Request.Url.PathAndQuery wich is used. I will try to upload an web sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample wich show our problem with Request.Url.PathAndQuery

Run this with Default.aspx?tutu
When you click on the second button, on a server, you will get :

> trans
>
> /Test/Default.aspx?trans

But if you run it on a dev machine, you will get :

> trans
>
> /Test/Default.aspx?tutu

Which in this case, is a false response

Default.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:button runat="server" text="?trans Preserve:TRUE" OnClick="Unnamed4_Click" style="height: 26px" />
            <asp:button runat="server" text="?trans Preserve:FALSE" OnClick="Unnamed3_Click" style="height: 26px" />
            <asp:button runat="server" text="Preserve:TRUE" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click" style="height: 26px" />
            <asp:button runat="server" text="Preserve:FALSE" OnClick="Unnamed2_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.vb :

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Response.Write(Request.QueryString)
        End If

    End Sub
    Protected Sub Unnamed1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Server.Transfer("Default2.aspx", True)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Unnamed2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Server.Transfer("Default2.aspx", False)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Unnamed4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Server.Transfer("Default2.aspx?trans", True)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Unnamed3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Server.Transfer("Default2.aspx?trans", False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Default2.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default2.aspx.vb :

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Default2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Response.Write(Request.QueryString)
        Response.Write("<br>")
        Response.Write(Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
    End Sub
End Class
```